# Argument of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $z=re^{i\theta}$ and $w=\rho e^{i \phi} $ are two complex numbers, then

$ arg(zw)=arg (z)+arg (w)$

But if $z=-1$ and $w=-1$, we get $ 0= 2\pi $  which is not correct. So why it gives us this result?

Comment: Why is $2\pi$ wrong? Can you explain.

Comment: Why is $2\pi$ wrong? Can you explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The summation formula you wrote is not correct. Instead it should be $$arg(zw) = arg(z) + arg(w) + 2 \pi k \qquad\text{for some integer $k$}$$ Keep in mind that $e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta)$ is periodic in the variable $\theta$, with periodicity $2\pi$.

Answer (score 4):

The arg function is one of the most important functions in analysis. It is defined in the punctured plane $\dot{\mathbb R}^2\sim\dot{\mathbb C}$. Its values are not real numbers, but equivalence classes of real numbers modulo $2\pi$. The sum of two such equivalence classes is a well defined such class, as is any integer multiple of an equivalence class. On the other hand ${1\over2}{\rm arg}(z)$ does not make sense.

The formula
$${\rm arg}(zw)={\rm arg}(z)+{\rm arg}(w)\qquad(z, \>w\in\dot{\mathbb C})\tag{1}$$
is absolutely correct.

Now for practical purposes we'd like to have a nicely behaved real-valued representant of ${\rm arg}(x,y)$, resp. ${\rm arg}(z)$, which then would be output by a pocket calculator upon entering of $x$ and $y$. The commonly accepted candidate for such a representant is the *principal value* ${\rm Arg}$ of ${\rm arg}$, which is defined by
$${\rm Arg}(x,y):={\rm the}\bigl({\rm arg}(x,y)\>\cap\ ]{-\pi},\pi[\,\bigr)\ ,$$
if $(x,y)\ne(-|x|,0)$, and undefined otherwise. If $x>0$, and only then, one has
$${\rm Arg}(x,y)=\arctan{y\over x}\ .$$
The principal value ${\rm Arg}$ does not satisfy the  functional equation $(1)$ universally, but the following rule of thumb is helpful: If  both $z$ and $w$ are lying in the right half-plane then $(1)$ is true also for ${\rm Arg}$.

A pornographic version of ${\rm Arg}$ is the function ${\tt atan2}$ available in some programming languages. But note that the order of $x$ and $y$ is reversed there.